# Is special variable $. gone from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

When processing a file, I used to use the special variable `$.` to get the last line number being read. For instance, the following program

```
require 'csv'

IFS=';'
CSV_OPTIONS = { col_sep: IFS, external_encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1, internal_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8 }

CSV.new($stdin, CSV_OPTIONS).each do |row|
  puts "::::line #{$.} row=#{row}"
end
```

is supposed to dump a CSV file (where the fields are delimited by semicolon instead of comma, as is the case in our project) and prepend each output line by the line number.

After updating Ruby to

```
_ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-cygwin]_
```

the lines are still dumped, but the line number is always displayed as zero.

What strikes me, is that this [Ruby Wiki](https://ruby.fandom.com/wiki/Special_variable) on special Ruby variables, while still having `$.` in its list, doesn't have a description for this variable anymore. So I wonder: Is this variable gone, or was it never supposed to work with the *csv* class and just worked for me by accident in the earlier versions?

Comment: The documentation for Ruby 2.6.3 still includes the [`$.` predefined global variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/globals_rdoc.html) which stores _the current input line number of the last file that was read._ That means the probably the implementation of `CSV` change.

Comment: What would be wrong with `CSV.new($stdin, CSV_OPTIONS).each_with_index do |row, line|`? Why there is a need in a global variable in the first place?

Comment: Good idea! I was not aware that each_with_index would also work here. Wouldn't in this case be the whole file read into memory first and then processed as array?

Comment: There is no difference between `each` and `each_with_index` behaviour.

Comment: I'm just surprised, because [the docs for csv](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) don't even mention `each_with_index`. So I guess the method is inherited from `Enumerable`, and that's why I was not sure weather this might not cause the whole file to be read into memory at once.

Comment: Use `each.with_index` then. I am not aware of what CSV provides in particular, but `each` returns an `Enumerator` instance when no block is given.

Comment: `each_with_index` will not cause the whole file to be read into memory at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `$.` isn't working for you, but it's also not the best solution here. When it works, `$.` gives you the number of lines read from input, but since quoted fields in a CSV file can span multiple lines the number you get from `$.` won't always be the number of *rows* that have been read.

As mentioned above, `each_with_index` is a good alternative:

```
CSV.new($stdin, CSV_OPTIONS).each_with_index do |row, i|
  puts "::::row #{i} row=#{row}"
end
```

Another alternative is [`CSV#lineno`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-lineno):

> #### lineno()
>
> The line number of the last row read from this file. Fields with nested line-end characters will not affect this count.

You would use it like this:

```
csv = CSV.new($stdin, CSV_OPTIONS)
csv.each do |row|
  puts "::::row #{csv.lineno} row=#{row}"
end
```

Note that `each_with_index` will start counting at 0, whereas `lineno` starts at 1.

You can see both approaches in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/LoudBlushingCharactercode